# What is an ABT scan test? What does the acronym stand for?

Tags: digital-logic

I am translating an electronics parts catalogue from English into Hungarian and have come across the phrase ‘ABT scan test’. I am a physicist with a limited background in electronics so I have tried to look it up but have only found datasheets (like [this](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=SN74LVTH18502APMR&HQS=ocb-tistore-invf-EDI-invf-store-null-eu)) which do not explain or even resolve the acronym.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Did you Google the acronym?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Texas Instruments it stands for: -

```
 Advanced BiCMOS Technology
```

See [this paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scba001a/scba001a.pdf?ts=1596993381501&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) for other details.

There's also [this paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scba008b/scba008b.pdf?ts=1596993488911&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and it's subtly different but it's title encapsulates the meaning of ABT: -

[image]

TI also make chips and [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvth18514.pdf?ts=1596993757308&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) encapsulates the words in the question title.

[image]